# Problem entering accented characters with Mac OS X 10.7.4 and MS Office

Tags: mac, ms-office

When I first installed MS Word for Mac on this MacBook Air, pressing and holding characters such as o and u produced a little menu of accents for that character - wonderful! But all of a sudden, this no longer works - the character just repeats like with an ordinary word-processing app. I tried disabling the Press and Hold to Repeat function in Apple preferences, but that just stopped the repeating, it didn't bring back the little accent menu. How can I reactivate this really useful feature?

Comment: Do you mean the character picker popovers provided by OS X? Do they still work in other applications like TextEdit?

Comment: While you wait for a fix, you can of course use the standard deadkey shortcuts, like option e then o gives you ó.  That is for the US keyboard layout.